# Repeating LIKE Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

Is there way to simplified the query before?

I must use the function to find words that contains a, b, c, etc.

```
IIf([T1].[as] LIKE ('*cat*')
OR [T1].[as] LIKE ('*dog*')
OR [T1].[as] LIKE ('*coke*') 
OR [T1].[as] LIKE ('*hi*') 
OR [T1].[as] Like ('*hello*') 
OR [T1].[as] Like ('*example*')
OR [T1].[as] Like ('*how*'), 1,0)
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: That is non-standard SQL. Which DBMS product are you using?

Answer (score 4):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

Let me speculate that you are using MS Access and intend `iif()`.  Then you can shorten this to:

```
select iif([T1].[as] LIKE '*[abcdefg]*', 1, 0)
```

Comment: Sorry I should have made it clear a, b, c, d, are examples... so I need to find columns that contains different words...

Comment: @HeeDoPark . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you asked.  Changing the question -- especially in a way that invalidates answers -- is rude.

Comment: sorry. I was not clear i did not mean a b c d as a letter i meant to use it as an example...  I am new to the post.  Is there anything to fix it for you?

Comment: Should i delete and repost?

Comment: @HeeDoPark . . . That's okay.  I clarified that this answer was before your edit.  Keep this in mind for your future questions.

Comment: @HeeDoPark . . . Actually, you might want to revert your change to this question (so this answer is then correct again) and ask another question.  New questions get more attention, and it is a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CONTAINS instead of LIKE

Comment: CONTAINS can search for:

    A word or phrase.

    The prefix of a word or phrase.

    A word near another word.

    A word inflectionally generated from another (for example, the word drive is the inflectional stem of drives, drove, driving, and driven).

    A word that is a synonym of another word using a thesaurus (for example, the word "metal" can have synonyms such as "aluminum" and "steel").